# URL encoding: difference between Django's iri_to_uri and w3school list

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding

Consider the word `Declaração` that I'm trying to put in a URL format.

What happens when I use [`iri_to_uri`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/#uri-and-iri-handling) from Django:

```
print iri_to_uri(u"Declaração")  # Declara%C3%A7%C3%A3o
```

What I obtain when I use the [list in w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp):

```
Declara%E7%E3o
```

1. Why are they different?
2. I'm trying to obtain the latter using Django/Python. Any way to do it easily? (3rd party is using it and there is no way around...)

Comment: probably because w3school sucks. This site has loads of errors and doubious statements. If you want to reference anything about web technologies and standard, http://www.w3.org/head to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ and

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea what http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp is doing, but output of it cannot be properly unqoted in Python.

```
import urlparse

print urlparse.unquote('Declara%E7%E3o')
# Declara��o
print urlparse.unquote('Declara%C3%A7%C3%A3o')
# Declaração
```

But that would be not the first time, when www.w3schools.com sucks, this is really bad place to learn anything - loads of errors and unprecise statements.

I would recommend http://w3.org and http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US instead.